# How to display Section for certain time

Tags: query, featured-post

i am building a News site. I want to display 1 featured post from "prime" category for only few hours. after it should be expired or disappeared from the section.

please have a look [here](http://www.firstpost.com/) u can see the post on top.

```
 <div id="prime_news" class="col-full">
 <?php $the_query = new WP_Query('category_name=prime&showposts=1&orderby=post_date&order=desc'); 
    if ($the_query->have_posts()) :?>
<div id="prime_headline">
<?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="prime_left fl">
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="" class="title_slide"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<p class="prime_excerpt"><?php echo limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), '190'); ?><span  class="read-more"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e('&#2310;&#2327;&#2375;  &#2346;&#2338;&#2375;...', 'BharatNews'); ?></a></span></p></div>
<div class="prime_right fr"><?php bharti_get_image('image',560,320,' '.$GLOBALS['align']); ?></div>
</div><div class="clear"></div> 
    <?php endif; ?>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [time parameter on WP_Query Class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters). There is a example on how to show posts form last 30 days. You can do it for last couple of hours, minutes or even seconds! Code is tested and working.

```
$args = array(
                            'posts_per_page' => 1, // We are showing only one post
                            'category_name' => 'prime' // showing form category prime
                            );


add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' ); ?>

 <div id="prime_news" class="col-full">
 <?php
    if ($the_query->have_posts()) :?>
<div id="prime_headline">
<?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="prime_left fl">
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="" class="title_slide"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<p class="prime_excerpt"><?php echo limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), '190'); ?><span  class="read-more"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e('&#2310;&#2327;&#2375;  &#2346;&#2338;&#2375;...', 'BharatNews'); ?></a></span></p></div>
<div class="prime_right fr"><?php bharti_get_image('image',560,320,' '.$GLOBALS['align']); ?></div>
</div><div class="clear"></div> 
    <?php endif; ?>

 </div>
```

**Add this function on `functions.php`**

```
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    // posts published last 30 minutes
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-30 minutes')) . "'";
    return $where;
}
```

Comment: i tried this.... but nothing happened. it showing blank .... (see: http://alturl.com/3p3k8 ) please have a look my code http://pastebin.com/2vTLPzQm

Comment: change `strtotime('+ 1 hours'))` to `strtotime('-1 hours'))` Note the `( - ) negative` sign.

Comment: great its working ... but a small problem. i count excerpts '240' but its showing default '55' <?php echo limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), '240'); ?>

Comment: now i posted this 'prime_news' at 10:21 am still showing at 1:21 

what it's means  ' date('Y-m-d', strtotime('- 2 hours')) '

Comment: @Nisha_Behance: check [this page for excerpt length](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt#Control_Excerpt_Length_using_Filters). And don't use space between negative sign and number.

Comment: A last question !! 'prime_news' working fine, what should i do if i want to hide 'prime_news' hide after 30 minutes or 2 hours of post ? i tried this but not working 


AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('- 2 hours')) . "'";

and 

  $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 minutes')) . "'";

Comment: Lets discuss it on chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/stoppress

Comment: updated the code should work now :)

Comment: Sisir, although *tasted* is quite poetic, on you next edit: "..the code is not *tested*.." :)

Comment: @brasofilo: Done :) actually it was tasted/tested on last edit but my word checker did failed me there ;)

Comment: @Sisir did you test it ?

Comment: @Nisha_Behance: yes, the code is working on my part. confirmed!

Comment: @Sisir mine is not working... can you plz take a look my site i'll give u pswd/username !!

Comment: @Nisha_Behance: send me an email with details

Comment: sent on support [a] txxxxxx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4255/discussion-between-nisha-behance-and-sisir)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using a shortcode. Here is a function that adds a shortcode called `expire` that you can add a value to with date and time when you want the content to be hidden.

```
/**
 * Make a simple expire shortcode
 * Example: [expires hide="2012-07-18 20:00:00"]
*/

function pa_hideafter_shortcode( $args = array(), $content = '' ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'hide' => 'tomorrow',
        ),
        $args
    ));
    if ( strtotime( $hide ) > time() ) {
        return $content;
    }
    return '';
}

add_shortcode('expires', 'pa_hideafter_shortcode');
```

And put this shortcode in your editor: `[expires hide="2012-07-18 20:00:00"] Your content here [/expires]`

This content will be hidden today after 20:00.

Or you can use an if statement to check if its true or not by adding the current time and add +1 hour and check on either `the_time` or `post_date` Try this:

```
<div id="prime_news" class="col-full">
    <?php
    // The time right now + one hour
    $time_remove = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime ( '+1 hour' . date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) ) );
    ?>

    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query('category_name=prime&showposts=1&orderby=post_date&order=desc'); ?>

    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <div id="prime_headline">
            <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?><?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php if( $time_remove <= the_time('Y-m-d H:i:s') ) : ?>

                <div class="prime_left fl">
                    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="" class="title_slide"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <p class="prime_excerpt">
                        <?php echo limit_words( get_the_excerpt(), '190'); ?>
                        <span  class="read-more">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e('&#2310;&#2327;&#2375;  &#2346;&#2338;&#2375;...', 'BharatNews'); ?></a>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="prime_right fr">
                        <?php bharti_get_image('image',560,320,' '.$GLOBALS['align']); ?>
                </div>

            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
```

This is untested on my system but it is pretty straight forward. Make a variable with the current date + the time you want the post to be displayed i.e 1 hour **( Change it in `$time_remove` )** then get the posts publish time with `the_time('Y-m-d H:i:s')` and check if the $time_remove is [Less than or equal to](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp) (<=) to the publish date `the_time('Y-m-d H:i:s')` then display the post.

Comment: thanks @Pontus but time still showing here http://alturl.com/fkt54 & if i want to display post only for few hours ?

Comment: it's not working, plz check site. section not showing