# How to rename  'TAG' to 'TOPIC'

Tags: tags

i want to rename TAG to TOPIC

and url it should be

wordpress.stackexchange.com/tag/ to wordpress.stackexchange.com/topic/

is it possible ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sub>**Click on the image to enlarge.**</sub>

[image: screenshot]

The screenshot shows the **Permalinks** settings screen. To do what you want, specify **topic** in the **Tag base** field/box.

Comment: thanks @Aahan Krish a lot. can u plz help me with this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58897/how-to-display-section-for-certain-time ?

Comment: Hi Nisha, if Aahan's answer solved your problem then you should mark it as correct. Please read the [About](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/about) and [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq) pages to learn how this site works.

Comment: Aahan i already voted

Comment: oh .. sorry it's done